# Random string not random

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to create a random string into my DB for users. It's a part of passwordless login.

So I have a field that is supposed to generate a random string. But I just found out it does not. It acctually generates same string over and over. Maybe each 5-10 min it will generate a new string for several minutes.

My model looks like this.

```
class Random(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    random = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=uuid.uuid4().hex[:25].upper(), unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Even though it's generating a 25 long string, it duplicates it over and over.

Since I have unique true, that results in next call for creating a string is not possible, since it's not unique.

How come it's creating unique each time?

Comment: `default=uuid.uuid4()` here `uuid.uuid4()` is evaluated once, when the server first executes and the model defined.

Comment: @sumpen are there any reasons to skip a part of uuid4?

Comment: @funnydman I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @sumpen why do you need `uuid.uuid4().hex[:25]`? it looks odd and I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: @funnydman And what would I use instead?

Comment: @sumpen check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your default value will be calculated before runtime, not during it. You'll need to define a callable object instead, which according to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default), will be called "every time a new object is created".

Example:

```py
def calculate_random():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex[:25].upper()

class Random(models.Model):
    random = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=calculate_random, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `UUIDField` it is designed to store `uuid` and will be translated to corresponding DB type, `uuid` if database support it else CharField will be used as a fallback.

For example:

```
import uuid

class Random(models.Model):  
    random = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```

It's simple and straightforward.

Comment: I don't understand why this is better than the other answer? Can I choose length of string with this solution also?

Comment: @sumpen uuid4 format is strictly defined and has 36 characters, and can not has more or fewer, if this rule is broken (here much more of them) it is not `uuid` anymore. If you need *real* uniqueness don't truncate it.

Comment: @sumpen this one is the _real_ correct answer, as it makes proper use of `uuid` - truncating the string representation of your uuid defeats the whole point of using uuids at all (and you'll have a hard time getting something better than a proper uuid if you want random unique identifiers).

Comment: @funnydman So this way, it will generate a new unique uuid with every new entry to the db?

Comment: @sumpen yes, the unique UUID will be generated for every new record.

Comment: @funnydman Damn. It worked on my dev setup but broke my production server :/

Comment: @funnydman fyi, it said that field random did not exist. I had to roll back.